# Rate of convergence of the coverage probability of bootstrap confidence intervals

Tags: probability, bootstrap, convergence

I was wondering if someone knows good books or references that deal with this subject :

"The rate of convergence of the coverage probability of bootstrap confidence intervals"

Many thanks for your help,
Philippe

Comment: Different statistics converge with different rates: sample mean of i.i.d. data, $O(n^{-1/2})$, sample mode, $O(n^{-1/3})$, kernel density estimate, $O(n^{-1/5})$, regression slopes in time series models with trend, $O(T^{-1})$. So I am not sure what you are asking about. I imagine Peter Hall's book has most answers.